# How do I include #include "File1" to "File2" and "File3" with seperated classes? C++

Tags: c++, class, header

C++ Codeblocks help!
Okay, I have no idea how to explain this more then I just did in the question's name,
but I hope you get the idea. If not, don't worry, you will when you see this code:

```
//File1 (NOT main.cpp)
#ifndef FILE1_H
#define FILE1_H
class File1
{
     doSomethingPlease();
};

#endif


//File2 (NOT main.cpp)
#ifndef FILE2_H
#define FILE2_H

#include "File1.h"
File1 f1; //This is the error part.
#endif
```

I don't think I can be more specific without posting my spaghetti code (for a text RPG Game with many separate class files, for easier debugging)

I just want to know how to include separated class files into other separated class files, because I've searched for HOURS after my problem, but I have found nothing.

Now comes the ERROR PART:E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Battle.cpp|99|undefined reference to `quit::quitGame()'|
I don't think you want me to post actual code, since it is almost unreadable, except for me.

Another problem I had, caused by the same code, was that (it said earlier, but I might have fixed it without knowing it) that "multiple definitions of File1, first in File2.cpp, second in File3.cpp".

```
ERROR CODES: obj\Debug\Battle.o||In function `Z6battlev':|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Battle.cpp|99|undefined reference to `quit::quitGame()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Battle.cpp|150|undefined reference to `Mainmenu::mainMenu()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Battle.cpp|170|undefined reference to `Mainmenu::mainMenu()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Battle.cpp|182|undefined reference to `Mainmenu::mainMenu()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Battle.cpp|233|undefined reference to `quit::quitGame()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Battle.cpp|281|undefined reference to `Mainmenu::mainMenu()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Battle.cpp|296|undefined reference to `Mainmenu::mainMenu()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Battle.cpp|308|undefined reference to `Mainmenu::mainMenu()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Battle.cpp|316|undefined reference to `Mainmenu::~Mainmenu()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Battle.cpp|316|undefined reference to `Levelup::~Levelup()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Battle.cpp|316|undefined reference to `Mainmenu::~Mainmenu()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Battle.cpp|316|undefined reference to `Levelup::~Levelup()'|
obj\Debug\Battle.o||In function `ZN6BattleC2Ev':|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Battle.cpp|319|undefined reference to `vtable for Battle'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Battle.cpp|321|undefined reference to `Battle::battle()'|
obj\Debug\Forest.o||In function `Z6forestv':|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Forest.cpp|42|undefined reference to `Mainmenu::mainMenu()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Forest.cpp|49|undefined reference to `Mainmenu::mainMenu()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Forest.cpp|56|undefined reference to `Mainmenu::mainMenu()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Forest.cpp|68|undefined reference to `Mainmenu::mainMenu()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Forest.cpp|75|undefined reference to `Battle::battle()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Forest.cpp|83|undefined reference to `Mainmenu::mainMenu()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Forest.cpp|85|undefined reference to `Battle::~Battle()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Forest.cpp|85|undefined reference to `Mainmenu::~Mainmenu()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Forest.cpp|85|undefined reference to `Levelup::~Levelup()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Forest.cpp|85|undefined reference to `Battle::~Battle()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Forest.cpp|85|undefined reference to `Mainmenu::~Mainmenu()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Forest.cpp|85|undefined reference to `Levelup::~Levelup()'|
obj\Debug\Forest.o||In function `ZN6ForestC2Ev':|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Forest.cpp|88|undefined reference to `vtable for Forest'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Forest.cpp|90|undefined reference to `Forest::forest()'|
obj\Debug\Levelup.o||In function `Z7levelUpv':|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Levelup.cpp|75|undefined reference to `Mainmenu::mainMenu()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Levelup.cpp|76|undefined reference to `Mainmenu::~Mainmenu()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Levelup.cpp|76|undefined reference to `Mainmenu::~Mainmenu()'|
obj\Debug\Levelup.o||In function `ZN7LevelupC2Ev':|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Levelup.cpp|80|undefined reference to `vtable for Levelup'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Levelup.cpp|82|undefined reference to `Levelup::levelUp()'|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\main.cpp|43|undefined reference to `Mainmenu::mainMenu()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\main.cpp|43|undefined reference to `Mainmenu::~Mainmenu()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\main.cpp|43|undefined reference to `Mainmenu::~Mainmenu()'|
obj\Debug\Mainmenu.o||In function `Z8mainMenuv':|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Mainmenu.cpp|36|undefined reference to `Levelup::levelUp()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Mainmenu.cpp|49|undefined reference to `quit::quitGame()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Mainmenu.cpp|88|undefined reference to `Forest::forest()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Mainmenu.cpp|90|undefined reference to `Levelup::~Levelup()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Mainmenu.cpp|90|undefined reference to `Forest::~Forest()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Mainmenu.cpp|90|undefined reference to `Levelup::~Levelup()'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Mainmenu.cpp|90|undefined reference to `Forest::~Forest()'|
obj\Debug\Mainmenu.o||In function `ZN8MainmenuC2Ev':|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Mainmenu.cpp|93|undefined reference to `vtable for Mainmenu'|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\Mainmenu.cpp|95|undefined reference to `Mainmenu::mainMenu()'|
obj\Debug\quit.o||In function `ZN4quitC2Ev':|
E:\Codeblocks Projects\Dungeons & Orcs\quit.cpp|13|undefined reference to `quit::quitGame()'|
||=== Build finished: 46 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

Comment: I think I'm as confused as you are.

Comment: Where in the code you posted is `quit::quitGame()`? How can the line of code you say produces the error, actually produce the error?

Comment: Don't use global variables.  Don't define variables in header files (which violates the one definition rule).

Comment: Thanks for your answers, people! Btw, how did you manage to find my post? I'm impressed that I got answers so fast. Anyways, back to the problem.

Comment: The problem is that I use multiple class files, seperated, and they are ALL dependant on eachother to work, as a relevant example:
I have a class Battle.cpp, which is dependant of Player.cpp, because
Player.health has to be included into battle.cpp, so I use Player.cpp
to tell 
player.health -= orc.damage;

Comment: I hope that clarified everything for you guys - Einar

Comment: Also, if this happens to clarify even more, I actually from the beginning, as the noob I am, wrote ALL functions in main.cpp, and then created classes one by one for those functions, because they contain a lot of code. So, considering that my classes are made out of functions (basically), maybe that could help figure the problem out. - Einar

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to include the header file that you are trying to define. #include should only be in your header file if you are trying to implement inheritance from other header files. For example:

```
#include "File1.h"
class File2 : public File1
{
};
```